# How to dynamically override superclass functions using generics

Tags: java, generics

If you have a base class that is in a jar file that looks like:

```
public class A {

public void awesome(int i){

}

}
```

...which is extended by these classes (also in a jar) as follows:

```
public class A1 extends A {

@Override
public void awesome(int i){

}

}
```

and

```
public class A2 extends A {

@Override
public void awesome(int i){

}

}
```

...is it possible to override the base function in a generic way?

Say there is an implementation that was being added via anonymous inner class - can you code that such that the entire anonymous inner implementation only appears once?
So instead of:

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String args[]){

    A1 mySpecialA1 = new A1(){
        @Override
        public void awesome(int i){
            //awesome implementation
        }
    };

    A2 mySpecialA2 = new A2(){
        @Override
        public void awesome(int i){
            //awesome implementation
        }
    };
}

}
```

...you could have (this is where it breaks down):

```
public class SpecialAFactory {

public static <T extends A> getSpecialA(){
    return new T(){
        @Override
        public void awesome(int i){
            //only once
        }
    };
}

}
```

So ultimately you would be passing in the subclass that you want to get a new anonymous instance of.

Comment: No, this is impossible with generics. You can't ever use `new T` since without knowing the concrete class in question the compiler can't know which constructor you mean -- or which superclass you mean (the compiler must generate a class file for class, even if it's anonymous). And I guess I've only given you one of many reasons why this can't ever work.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Thanks, that's kind of what I thought. Now I'm wondering if there is there some Java kung fu way of using reflection etc to accomplish this, but I guess that's another question.

Comment: I think it woud be possible with one of the dynamic proxy libraries like javassist. The lib dynamically makes a subclass of any class you give it, and you supply the single implementation that will execute for all cases.

Answer (score 2):

Although you cannot do it with generics, there is a simple, easy to understand, solution that lets you avoid code duplication in cases like that:

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String args[]){

    A1 mySpecialA1 = new A1(){
        @Override
        public void awesome(int i){
            awesomeImplementation(i);
        }
    };

    A2 mySpecialA2 = new A2(){
        @Override
        public void awesome(int i){
            awesomeImplementation(i);
        }
    };
}

private static void awesomeImplementation(int i) {
    //awesome implementation
}

}
```

Comment: This is pretty good, but if the signature was modified to `private static void awesomeImplementation(int i, A a)` and `awesomeImplementation(i,this)` then it should work better.

Comment: @emory You are correct, `awesomeImplementation` will not have `this` or the locals of the `main` in its scope, so one would need to pass them as needed.

Comment: And won't work if `awesomeImplementation` needs to access or modify protected members from `A` or its subclasses.

Comment: @DavidHarkness it seemed to work for me.  I created an `A` class with a `protected String message` variable and my `awesomeImplementation` just `System.out.println(a.message);`  The `Test` class and `A` class were in the same package.

Comment: @emory - Yes, if they are in the same package you're fine. I assumed from the OP that `A` (in a JAR) comes from an external library.